# Which planet is also the name of an element?

Tags: planet

Which planet is also the name of an element?

I came across this question on cosmos quest and need and answer

Comment: Can't you just take the nine (eight?) planet names and look for each in an alphabetic list of the elements?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shown no previous investigation AT ALL.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not within the scope of this site and shows no attempt at prior investigation.

Comment: If you're going to count dwarf planets (Pluto/Plutonium), you should also count Cerium, which was named after Ceres (which was still classified as a planet when the element Cerium was named after it).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is **Mercury**.

**Plutonium** was made after **Pluto** was discovered.

Answer (score 5):

As per ReNiSh A R's post, the answer is Mercury.

A quick Google search took me here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_chemical_element_discoveries <= second result!

If you control-F search the page, you'll find the following:

Mercury - discovered before 2000BC, so the planet will have been named after the element

Plutonium - About 1940/41, meaning it would have been named after Pluto (before it was declassified as a planet)

Uranus - Uranium discovered around 1789

Neptune - Neptunium discovered 1940

In addition, the only one of those having exactly the same name for both the planet and the element is Mercury.

Answer (score 2):

```
Mercury -  Mercury(hg-80)
```

`Mercury` will be the Answer, Because `Mercury` is Very clear name with the 80th Element so planet is(However, Mercury was named after the `Roman God` which was related to what they called `quicksilver`).

Comment: Plain wrong. For Uranium, Neptunium and Plutonium it's the other way around.